# Disable Thunderbird Folder Expansion

Tags: directory, hide, account, thunderbird

I have recently setup Thunderbird in my machine.

I have setup two accounts, one for me and the other for my brother.

Is it possible to disable the expansion of the node for my Folder when I am not logged in to the gmail account?

I am asking this to provide privacy in between our folders.

Or would it be possible to set up Thunderbird so that when you open thunderbird, you can select which account to open and enter password. only then the account which you chose to open can be viewed.

If the password you supplied for an account is not correct, then you cannot view that folder or email of that account.

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking programming questions. You may be able to get help with this at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm... Isn't that what multiple computer user accounts are for?

Why are you sharing your computer account, but then want privacy in mail?